# Better Thinking Sphinx Results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have recently started playing around with the thinking sphinx gem and have been having great success with running searches, however I have noticed that for some reason, certain searches aren't returning the correct records.

config/thinking_sphinx.yml

```
development:
  mysql41: 3313
  morphology: stem_en
```

indicies/product_index.rb

```
indexes :title
```

lib/tasks/my_rake_task.rake

```
term = "Garmin Edge 500 GPS Enabled Computer"
@product = Product.search Riddle::Query.escape(term), ranker: :none
```

The rake task should match the title in the database of 'Garmin Edge 500 GPS Cycle Computer' however for some reason it returns an empty array. When I remove the term 'Enabled' it returns the record.

I was just wondering if there is a simple way to improve the accuracy of a search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Paul (just replied to the TS list, but here's my response again, with examples):

What you're trying to do (match some but not necessarily all words) is a little tricky, but here's a couple of things to note:

If you want to match on *any* word, rather than all, you can insert |'s between each word (| is Sphinx's OR). There is also the quorum operator, but that may be harder, given you don't have control over how many terms the user may enter.
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax

```
# Using ORs
Product.search "Garmin | Edge | 500 | GPS | Enabled | Computer"
# Using quorum
Product.search '"Garmin Edge 500 GPS Enabled Computer"/4'
```

Either way, you'll be slicing up the user-provided queries to count or split words, which is slightly annoying, but perhaps worthwhile.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Pat, this has certainly given me something to look at. With both of the examples that you have given I get results back now, so with some further work I am sure I can filter this list down even further.